# How to predict ABV in cider?

Tags: cider, hydrometer, alcohol-content

I am new to cider brewing (my first batch has just started fermenting). As I'm new and just want to trial the process before getting into something more involved, I used store bought juice (no additives etc).

I got myself a hydrometer, and have measured the OG (1.049) and understand that I will need to measure the FG to calculate the final ABV.

My question is this: if I need the FG to calculate the ABV, how does one predict the final outcome? Is the OG any indication of where you'll end up?

I didn't add any sugar to my batch, so worried the ABV might be too low?

Also, when I start my second batch, I'd like to aim for around 10%, so unsure how to work out how much sugar I should add to reach that volume.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the other answers, what you are looking for to determine how much sugar to add to your must (juice) is a Chaptalization calculator.

[image: winemakinganalyses.com calculator]

[Link to calculator here](http://winemakinganalyses.com/tools/chaptalization_cal.php#AnchorAbvCal)

What this calculator tells you is that at 1.049 SG, if the must ferments to near complete dryness, you would have an ABV of 6.5%. By increasing the SG to 1.075, if the must ferments to near complete dryness you would have an ABV of 10%. The 9 ounces of sugar you would need to add has a potential ABV of 3.5% when dissolved into 1 gallon of liquid. So the current 6.5% & potential 3.5% add up to 10%.

You may want to ferment to complete dryness & then back-sweeten a bit depending on whether you desire a sweet cider or not & also considering whether you want some sugar remaining at bottling to produce carbonation.

Comment: This would be using .133 as a multiplying factor.

Answer (score 3):

you can predict ABV by using the yield calculation, Safcider gives 1% of ABV for 16.3g/l

```
1049 ~ 135 g/l 
therefore 
135/16.3 => 8.2% ABV
```

Or you can get more complex by looking through these equations, but that is overkill for a quick homebrew, unless like me you are a bit of a science/maths geek: http://realbeer.com/spencer/attenuation.html